# How do I evaluate sentences from a dataframe instead of a single list

Tags: python, google-sheets

So, I [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74985783/how-do-i-convert-googlesheets-columns-into-a-python-key-value-dictionary/74985876#74985876) have this code:

```
import pandas as pd

diccionario = pd.read_csv(dict, header=0).set_index("nombre")["valor"].to_dict()

lista = ["felicidad", "paz", "día", "estoy", "isla", "alivio", "-"]
print(sum([diccionario[i] for i in lista if i in diccionario]))
```

that allow me to compare the words from "lista" with a key:value dictionary (dictionario), and I get as result *8*.

But, now I would like to read "lista" also from the same google sheet, in order to be able to add more lists.

So, here I added the new lists here:

> ```
> b = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-odw996EIUB9mo2Ad1fNh0y9QiXv7GU81COMj6g1Z-A/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=b"
> ```

and read it

```
import pandas as pd

text = pd.read_csv(b, header=0)
```

Then, I tokenize the phrases with NLTK

```
regexp = RegexpTokenizer('\w+')

text['text_token']=text['frases'].apply(regexp.tokenize)
```

But once I use the same code, I dont recieve a new column with the evaluation of each phrase

```
text['suma']=(diccionariob[diccionariob['nombre'].isin(text['frases'])]['valor'].sum())
print(sum([diccionario[i] for i in lista if i in diccionario]))
```

Instead, all I got are zeros.

| frases | text_token | suma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hola la casa es bonita paz felicidad | [hola, la, casa, es, bonita, paz, felicidad] | 0 |
| pasos de gigante feliz alegria mejor paz | [pasos, de, gigante, feliz, alegria, mejor] | 0 |
| estás muy bien paz | [estás, muy, bien, paz] | 0 |
| mucha felicidad paz | [mucha, felicidad, paz] | 0 |

What am I missing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to wrap your first method into a lambda function (assuming you have all the tokenized words inside a dictionary called diccionariob)

```
#pass dictionary and the tokenized list as parameters
def somma(dictionary, lista):
    somma = sum([dictionary[i] for i in lista if i in dictionary])
    return somma

#apply the function to each row of the dataframe
text['suma']= text.apply(lambda x: somma(diccionariob, x['frases']), axis=1)
```

Comment: hi @esimo. I wasnt able to make the lambda function work. here is the code that i used #pass dictionary and the tokenized list as parameters
def somma(dictionario, lista):
    somma = sum([dictionario for i in lista if i in dictionario])
    return somma


#apply the function to each row of the dataframe
text['suma']= text.apply(lambda x: somma(diccionariob, x['text_token']), axis=1)

Comment: Hi @Saríah, 
you can check if your function works properly doing something like
    print(somma(dictionario, ["felicidad", "paz", "día", "estoy", "isla", "alivio", "-"]))

Maybe you missed the key after the first dictionario in the function:
  def somma(dictionario, lista): 
       somma = sum([dictionario[i] for i in lista if i in dictionario]) 
       return somma

Comment: hi @esino! thank u so much! yes, it worked... i had misspelled a parameter... an all is working fine now.